# Are there countries where the Roma have integrated into local society?

Tags: crime, discrimination, society

I live in Czech Republic and the Roma minority here is considered to be the biggest source of crime - most prisoners belong to the Roma ethnic even though they only make up 2-3% of the population.

Are there currently any countries where the Roma have integrated into local society? And if so, why don't the Central/Eastern European countries use their experience?

My definition of *integrated* is: the median income and crime levels of that ethnic group are close to (or better than) the median of the native population. A good example would be Nigerians in the US.

Comment: How do you define "fully integrated"?  And how do you identify "the Roma" if they are fully integrated into society?  What would a society that has a fully integrated yet still readily identifiable minority population look like?

Comment: @phoog Jews in the US?

Comment: Do you mean fully integrated while still nomads, or fully integrated and settled down ?

Comment: @user5751924 fully integrated and settled down. Similar to how most Jews no longer live in closed communities these days.

Comment: I hear North Africa has nomads who are integrated without settling.

Comment: @phoog This would fit populations that were once distinct identifiable minority populations that ceased to be ethnically distinct due to their integration. In the case of the Roma, one could meaningfully describe pretty much anyone with South Asian ancestry in Europe whose ancestors migrated to Europe pre-1500 CE as "historically Roma", even if they do not identity as Roma now (with the exception of the South Asian descended people of Cres Island, Croatia who probably arrived in Europe ca. 841 CE (about 240 years prior to the Roma departure from India)).

Comment: I have removed "fully" since it is unclear in an effort to prevent the question being closed. What about people living under poverty line, maybe not being able to read or even not having access to electricity regardless of their ethnicity. Are they "fully integrated"?

Comment: I will try to provide an answer from Romania's perspective in 1-2 days, since Romani is an unsolved issue for more than a century and it receives media coverage quite regularly.

Comment: In spain,some of them have integrated in the communities that adopted them, some haven't. The ones that lived before the war have a settled down, educated and above-poverty way of living that clearly differentiates them from the post civil war and post ww2 migration newcomers,  who still live the nomad way sometimes. There had been clan fights once every sime time, and there is ethnical tension between the newcomers and the already settled families, but in the last 30 years its been reduced to a marginality, currently their violent incidents equal those of the eastern crime gangs,quite low.

Comment: Peret (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peret), Lo Parrano, are some examples  established strong personalities in the Romani community. The Romani community of Lleida center, Barcelona's Gràcia Street and Hostafrancs and the Barceloneta are examples of settled down bilingual/trilingual comunities. many artists come from there, the most famous right now in spain being  Sabor de Gràcia, Estopa, melendi, Gertrudis, and Txarango, mainstream spanish artists with millions of of  followers. examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDaU6T6txVQ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brtt419Pi9I

Comment: Do you mean "integrated" or "assimilated"? You do not need to be indistinguishable or living a mainstream life to be integrated, but you need it to be assimilated. I would define "integrated" as having a generally accepted place in the society (except for some fringe groups). This can be anything from being seen as special, but okay, to fully assimilated where only different skin color or foreign-sounding names give a hint to the origin.

Comment: @Thern integrated = their median income and crime levels are close to the median among natives.

Comment: @JonathanReez Maybe it is worth to add this definition to your question. (Although this leads to the consequence that low-wage workers are not defined as integrated, which might be a problematic point of view, and to the strange assumption that groups with higher median income and lower crime levels are also not integrated. I can see some merits in this definition, but it is controverse.)

Comment: @Thern post updated with an improved definition. "Low wage workers" are not an ethnicity so you can't measure their integration.

Comment: @JonathanReez look at my examples on the comments. there is indeed a large group of Roma in Spain that have fully integrated (median income and crime equals to those with the same education levels on native population), mostly thanks to the education programmes of the 80's in some regions, they're still a small subset, but growing. last year, over 60 roma adults aged 35-45 enrolled in adult university degrees (over 25yo  special grant) in barcelona, and it's the 2nd year this exists.  the government of Catalonia's website with news & data: http://www.museuvirtualgitano.cat/en/

Comment: @JonathanReez I know it's a "Bart's people"-esque story but this sums it up, had many roma friends that dropped studies due to "family pressure"  ("you're roma, you gotta work with us, not read books") or "school pressure" ("you're roma, you won't get anywhere else than blue collar") and then went  back to it to get higher degrees, now to be the "hero" of that family. http://www.museuvirtualgitano.cat/en/2016/10/21/leducacio-significa-oportunitat-possibilitats-i-futur/

Comment: I would also point out that "most prisoners" being from an oppressed group does not mean that the group is the biggest source of crime.  Other factors at play include discrimination in the criminal justice system and the fact that crime committed by corrupt insiders usually either goes unpunished or is falsely attributed to a member of an oppressed minority group.

Comment: Yet another Question with nothing to do with "politics" as defined here, but somehow it is not instantly close-voted.

Answer (score 7):

I will try to provide an answer from Romania's perspective which [has one of the largest communities of Roma people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_diaspora#Population_by_country): ~850000. It might also explain, at least in part, Bulgaria's issues in integrating Roma people.

So, I will cover the final question, since it is more answerable:

> Why don't the Central/Eastern European countries use their [countries
>   where the Roma have integrated into local society] experience?

First, it is important to understand that most of people in Romania are Romanians, not Romani. Of course, this resemblance creates confusion and some argued that they should be named "Țigani":

> In 2009-2010, a media campaign followed by a parliamentarian
>   initiative asked the Romanian Parliament to accept a proposal to
>   change back the official name of country's Roma (adopted in 2000) to
>   Țigan (Gypsy), the traditional and colloquial Romanian name for
>   Romani, in order to avoid the possible confusion among the
>   international community between the words Roma — which refers to the
>   Romani ethnic minority — and Romania.[20] The Romanian government
>   supported the move on the grounds that many countries in the European
>   Union use a variation of the word Țigan to refer to their Gypsy
>   populations. **The Romanian upper house, Senate, rejected the proposal**

However, [this is considered a pejorative term](https://journals.openedition.org/transtexts/251) and one using it in an official discourse (TV, radio, newspaper) can be subject to fines from [National Council for Combating Discrimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Council_for_Combating_Discrimination).

Coming back to the question at hand, the problem is really complex. Historically, Romani were slaves in Romania before 1856 and subject to deportation under Romanian fascist government of Ion Antonescu (WWII).

I do not know about other countries experience in integrating Romani people, but locally there are many issues that make their integration hard to obtain:

**- discrimination**: Roma people face a great discrimination as mentioned in the Wikipedia article. This makes integration programs harder to implement (e.g. think about parents not agreeing their children having Roma colleagues):

> A 2000 EU report about Romani said that in Romania… the continued high
>   levels of discrimination are a serious concern.. and progress has been
>   limited to programmes aimed at improving access to education.
>
> A survey of the Pro Democraţia association in Romania revealed that
>   94% of the questioned persons believe that the Romanian citizenship
>   should be revoked to the ethnic Roms who commit crimes abroad.

**- corruption**: EU and other political actors allocated funds to help with Roma integration, but [there are serious issues about how these funds were used](https://www.occrp.org/en/daily/4959-romania-lawmakers-suspected-in-eu-roma-fund-fraud):

Parliamentarians Madalin Voicu and Nicolae Paun are under investigation along with 10 other suspects for an array of financial offenses relating to the alleged **misuse of European Union (EU) funds intended to help the minority Roma population.**

As a side note, [Madalin Voicu also had a very controversial political discourse](http://www.errc.org/roma-rights-journal/being-a-gypsy-the-worst-social-stigma-in-romania) about Romani people in Romania.

[This article](https://ec.europa.eu/anti-fraud/media-corner/news/22-02-2016/romanian-members-parliament-prosecuted-following-olaf-investigation_en) emphasizes the problem:

> GERMANY is trying to seize billions of pounds from Romania and
>   Bulgaria meant for the Roma community after claiming they do not use
>   it.
>
> Joachim Stamp, integration minister for Germany's largest state, North
>   Rhine Westphalia, said he finds it "extremely annoying" the two
>   eastern European countries refuse to use funds from the European
>   Social Fund (ESF) for its proper use.

**- cultural differences**: many people perceive that there is great (and unsolvable) cultural gap between Roma and themselves. One particular example is [early age marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people_in_Romania#Early_age_marriage_scandal) (below age of consent).

As a conclusion, Roma's integration heavily depends on the context (use the funds properly, how the others perceive them and are willing to accept that they can indeed be integrated) and "other countries" experience might not be relevant.

Answer (score 7):

The [Dom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dom_people) (in North Africa and the Middle East) and [Lom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lom_people) (in the Middle East) people are, insofar as I'm aware, relatively well integrated compared to their [Romani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people) cousins in Europe.

The thing with North Africa and the Middle East is that they didn't have anything comparable to the level of [Anti-Romanyism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Romanyism) - culminating with the [Porajmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porajmos) during WW2 - that prevailed in Europe since their arrival. To give you a taste:

> In 1710, Joseph I, Holy Roman Emperor, issued an edict against the Romani, ordering "that all adult males were to be hanged without trial, whereas women and young males were to be flogged and banished forever." In addition, in the kingdom of Bohemia, Romani men were to have their right ears cut off; in the March of Moravia, the left ear was to be cut off. In other parts of Austria, they would be branded on the back with a branding iron, representing the gallows. These mutilations enabled authorities to identify the individuals as Romani on their second arrest. The edict encouraged local officials to hunt down Romani in their areas by levying a fine of 100 Reichsthaler for those failing to do so. Anyone who helped Romani was to be punished by doing a half-year's forced labor. The result was "mass killings" of Romani. In 1721, Charles VI amended the decree to include the execution of adult female Romani, while children were "to be put in hospitals for education".

Worth noting also is that there was still plenty of institutionalized discrimination against the Romani until recently. Spain, for instance, has around a million of Romani in total, and abolished its last anti-Romani laws [as recently as 1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people_in_Spain). In Bosnia and Herzegovina, the European Court of Human Rights had to step in against institutionalized discrimination [as recently as 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people_in_Bosnia_and_Herzegovina). And in some Central European countries, most notably [Romania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racism_in_Romania), [Bulgaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people_in_Bulgaria), and [Serbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people_in_Serbia), there is still overt discrimination or segregation even today. (Cursory googling should yield more countries in the area with serious problems; think Hungary, the Czech Republic, Slovakia, etc.)

Even countries like France, where they're mostly well integrated as already noted in a separate answer (the ones that got expelled in recent years were Romanian and Bulgarian migrants), have all sorts of administrative barriers in place to prevent groups of people (i.e. Romani) from wandering around and settling camps wherever they feel. The results are positive, in a sense: the [Gitans](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roms_en_France) [French article], which are related to the Romani in Spain and rather than to their Central European cousins, have become sedentary and integrated to the point where estimates of the number of Romani people living in France range from 20,000 to 1.3 million depending on who you ask.

[Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people_in_Turkey) is the main exception I can think of off the top of my head. The Ottoman empire wasn't exactly an angel when they first arrived. But they became muslim and integrated eventually. So much so that, somewhat like France, they don't even know precisely how many Romani live there - officially they're 500,000, but they could actually number 4 or 5 million.

At any rate, the point is that there are countries where discrimination is institutionalized or nearly so, making it hard for the Romani people to integrate at all, and countries where they're integrated to varying degree - with the occasional caveat that, to quote the Wiki page on the Dom people citing a study on the Dom people in Jordan, they sometimes need to "accommodate [...] racism by hiding their ethnic identity".

Answer (score 4):

Well, in France they are somehow integrated. They have been visible for quite a time and many artists claim to be from this culture or derived from it, like [gitanos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendji_Girac)

Some actually like to refer to the original "crimy" Romanis, like [Seth Gueko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seth_Gueko) and they are quite well liked in the socially diverse France!

When medias talk about them it's either to show how hard their lives is, or how hardcore criminals they are. [Jacques Mesrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Mesrine) is often associated with the pseudo "Romani-Mafia" that supposedly existed. Most people dislike a Romani camp near their home, but they actually like the "pros" of having them, like old-fashioned weavers, traditions etc that are not that common with the others "wild" cultures around.

Comment: "but they actually like the "pros" of having them, like old-fashioned weavers" - source? I haven't heard of that here in Czech Republic.

Comment: France [deported a whole bunch of Roma not too long ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deportation_of_Roma_migrants_from_France) (2009/2010). That doesn't exactly sound like "fully integrated" (or even "somewhat integrated") to me.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker "Roma" includes a whole lot of different subcultures. There are Roma which are "native" to France in the sense that they have lived there for many many generations. These are the ones Lama's answer refers to. And there are foreign Roma from completely different countries, like the Romani from Romania and Bulgaria your article refers to. Not the same thing.

Comment: @JonathanReez that might be "exclusive" to some subcultures that lives only in France, but there is quite a large number of interviews of Kendji (link above) where he talks about romani mariages and how beautifull the dresses are.

Comment: I am not sure how French media admiring (part of ) Rom culture and folklore while blaming them for most crimes make them a well-integrated minority.

Comment: @Evargalo The thing is, accepting it can be good and/or bad is much better than just stating they are savages. Lately in France we had a crime where a guy from Sri-Lanka beheaded another in a restaurant. No one ever talks about the Sri-Lanka community; so they aren't well-integrated; most people don't know they exist. Those that know they exist are inclined to think they are savages and criminals. It sounds worse than Romanis in France for me.

Comment: @LamaDelRay : I'll not debate what is better or worse for a given community, and I do not think there is more prejudice against Sri Lankans than against Romani, but in any case your definition of 'integration' is very different from the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

In Finland, the Romani (as they are called here) are so well integrated that it's almost impossible to see them as the same people as the Roma in Serbia, Bulgaria or Romania. They still maintain their own clothing style, but in terms of crime and living standards they are close to the median. Maybe not "fully integrated" as the asked question defines full integration, but the trend is towards that goal.